# Does browning/toasting cream impact its shelf life?

Tags: storage-lifetime, cream

Does browning/toasting cream in a pressure cooker impact its shelf life? The process seems similar to ultra-high-temperature processing.

Comment: How do you intend to store it ? this link says about 1 year in can 
https://www.experimentalbrew.com/blogs/drew/something-other-beer-toasted-cream

Comment: Cooking does not extend shelf life unless you process it and protect it in a sealed container.